# Como usar o While no Python 3?

Tags: python, matemática

Minha dúvida é sobre o laço `while`, não consigo entender o funcionamento dele.

Escreva uma função em Python que recebe, por argumento, dois números inteiros e retorna a soma
de todos os números inteiros entre os dois (incluindo os dois).

meu código...

```
def somatorio(x,y):
    count = 0
    soma = 0

    while count < y:
        soma = y + (y-count)
        count += 1
    return soma

print(somatorio(1,2))
print(somatorio(1,5))
```

Comment: O que você quer saber especificamente? Você usou algo que não sabe para que serve?

Comment: era sobre a condição, a dúvida já foi sanada, obrigado ^^

Comment: Só pra constar que este código está errado, pois ele não retorna "_a soma de todos os números inteiros entre os dois_", deveria ser algo assim: https://ideone.com/6b1iuW <-- neste link também tem outras opções de como fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `while` é um laço de repetição. Faz com que um conjunto de instruções seja executado enquanto uma condição é verdadeira. Quando essa condição deixa de ser verdadeira, o loop é interrompido, vide exemplo abaixo:

```
contador = 0
while(contador < 10):
    print(contador)
    contador = contador + 1
```

No exemplo acima, criamos um laço que executa o comando `print` por 10 vezes. Para criar uma variação, ou um laço infinito - muito utilizado em desenvolvimento de jogos - podemos fazer assim:

```
while(True):
    print("infinito")
```

Comment: Muitooo obrigado, essa parte da condição que estava me pegando...